# In Jquery dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have develope a program to get selected text from dropdown menu. This code is working in jsFiddle. but doesn't work in Browser. Is anything problem in jquery coding?

Dropdown

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#ddl').change(function(){  
        var text= $('#ddl :selected').text();
        $('#ddltext').html(text);     
    });

});
```

CSPIT
ADIT
BVM
DDIT
Nirma

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, check your console for errors!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#ddl').change(function(){
    var text= $('#ddl option:selected').text(); 
    $('#ddltext').html(text);
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/APNFd/

i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Plugins and change global variables name if it works with Jsfiddle not in browser this mean conflict in plugins scripts.
If this does not work please show us all of the codes to detect errors.